# Check Engine and VSC lights Toyota

Tags: engine, toyota, brakes, p0571

I have a Toyota Vitz (Japanese version of Yaris), 2014 model. The current mileage is around 22,000 KM. The Check Engine and the VSC lights went on last month and it went off after turning off the vehicle for sometime and starting it back. The Check Engine and VSC lights came back on today and went back off after stopping the engine for a while. The issue seems to be intermittent. I had it diagnosed and the error codes I've got are:

- P0571 - Brake Switch "A" Circuit
- C1201 - Engine Control System Malfunction

Any thoughts on this?

Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have the C1201 code because of the P0571 code. The P0571 code means your brake switch is faulty. On the back of the brake pedal is a switch that will either open or a close a circuit when the brake pedal is pressed or depressed (this operation varies from manufacturer).

If that circuit does not active (in the way it expects) then it will fail, causing codes. One of the issue is that cruise control cannot be deactivated, brake lights won't come on, etc even though you can still brake like normal. Either that or you have a blown fuse (more likely the brake switch).

here is an image I found on google for a brake switch for the yaris (most of them look like this, long with a plunger)
[image]

You can easily test this by pressing the brakes and checking if the brake lights come on.

When you fix the P0571 code, the C1201 code will go away.